# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Server Fault breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 11         46
Users destroyed                                 261          0
Users deleted                                     6          0
Users contacted                                  34          0
User banned from review                           0         10
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           953      9,176
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              421      1,472
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        355      1,973
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              280      4,258
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               938     17,391
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue            1,129      7,186
Tags merged                                       4          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             5          0
Tag synonyms created                              5          0
Revisions redacted                               10          0
Questions reopened                              168          3
Questions protected                              34         95
Questions migrated                              393         95
Questions merged                                  4          0
Questions flagged⁴                               43      2,086
Questions closed                              5,187      1,164
Question flags handled⁴                         977      1,152
Posts unlocked                                    4         75
Posts undeleted                                  48        278
Posts locked                                     27        937
Posts deleted⁵                                2,818     14,999
Posts bumped                                      0     17,460
Comments undeleted                               31          0
Comments flagged                                  1      5,156
Comments deleted⁶                             3,321      6,760
Comment flags handled                         1,807      3,350
Bounties canceled                                 4          0
Answers flagged                                 231      5,207
Answer flags handled                          4,614        824
All comments on a post moved to chat              5          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://serverfault.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Thanks for the statistics, and happy new years to everyone too!